# ReactJS Dynamic queue UI with animation

Tags: reactjs, queue, tailwind-css, css-animations

I would like to build a queue data structure in ReactJS, similar to the implementation in this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-implement-queue-data-structure-in-the-reactjs/. However, I would like elements to slide left (out of the page) when they are dequeued (grabbed) and slide in to the page from the right when they are enqueued (appended). When an element is dequeued, I would then like all the other elements to slide into their new positions, one-by-one. Furthermore, the horizontal view must be horizontally-scrollable. I realize this is a vague question, but I do not really know where to start with these animations. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks so much!

Andrew

P.S. I am using tailwind css. Thanks!

I have built the simple queue system without animation. I have the scrollable view with the queue elements working with scroll snapping, arrows for scrolling, etc. I have also been playing around with a basic slide in animation, as shown below:

```
        queuemove: {
          '0%': { transform: 'translateX(100%)' },
          '100%': { transform: 'translateX(0)' }
        }
```

However, this animation does not actually change the position of the element, merely animating to the left from on top of its later item on the queue. I have also figured out how to chain these animations, one-by-one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, I think what you're looking for is a carousel. Here's a light-weight react carousel that's pretty straight-forward and unopinionated when it comes to styling. So, you can use tailwind to style it the way you want.

http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/#demos

```
 <Carousel showArrows={true} onChange={onChange} onClickItem={onClickItem} onClickThumb={onClickThumb}>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/1.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 1</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/2.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 2</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/3.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 3</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/4.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 4</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/5.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 5</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="assets/6.jpeg" />
                    <p className="legend">Legend 6</p>
                </div>
            </Carousel>
```

Comment: Thank you for your note, Vikram! I have the queue logic working, but my question is pertaining to CSS animations in the ReactJS project. Do you have any thoughts as to how to have the queue objects animate in and out when they are pushed/popped?

Comment: Or is there any way to build the queue component by moving the items (sliding them over when the queue is grabbed from), as opposed to merely updating the state and re-rendering everything?

Comment: I updated my answer Andrew. See if it is helpful now